# compile FFmpeg error on windows when run ./configure

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to use FFmpeg to decode mp3 and acc on android, I use android-ndk-r7 and the newest cygwin.

I wrote a shell config.sh, which content is:

---

```
TMPDIR=/cygdrive/c/temp

PREBUILT=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows
PLATFORM=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-8/arch-arm

./configure --target-os=linux --arch=arm --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-ffprobe --disable-encoders --disable-muxers --disable-devices --disable-protocols --enable-protocol=file --enable-avfilter --disable-network --disable-mpegaudio-hp --disable-avdevice --enable-cross-compile --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm --extra-cflags="-fPIC -DANDROID" --disable-asm --enable-neon --enable-armv5te --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-T,$PREBUILT/arm-eabi/lib/ldscripts/armelf_linux_eabi.x -Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/crtbegin.o $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/crtend.o -lc -lm -ldl"
```

---

I open cmd and do bash to open cygwin shell, then do ./config, the problem is appeared:
"/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is unable to create an executable file..."

the config.log is:

```
check_ld
check_cc
BEGIN /cygdrive/c/temp/ffconf.SFJc3t92.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /cygdrive/c/temp/ffconf.SFJc3t92.c
gcc -fPIC -DANDROID -std=c99 -c -o /cygdrive/c/temp/ffconf.YKRv5TSp.o /cygdrive/c/temp/ffconf.SFJc3t92.c
/cygdrive/c/temp/ffconf.SFJc3t92.c:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
gcc -Wl,-rpath-link=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib -nostdlib /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_static.o /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtend_android.o -lc -lm -ldl -o /cygdrive/c/temp/ffconf.Yf1Ftjmo /cygdrive/c/temp/ffconf.YKRv5TSp.o
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_static.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_static.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
C compiler test failed.
```

I don't know what is happened, is there someone who know what is happened, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the path of your gcc set properly in cygwin. Are you trying to cross compile ffmpeg. In that case make sure you don't have the cross compiled version of gcc defined in your path.
many modules of ffmpeg do not compile in cygwin. Check if cygwin architecture is compatible. Check the options available under `--arch and --os.`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I thinki maybe the ffmpeg version can not run on cygwin. I follow another example to finished it on linux. here's the url, http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the solution to your problem: 
    http://thompsonng.blogspot.co.il/2010/06/ffmpeg-compiling-with-cygwin-window.html